# How to improve xerces parser performance when large comments are present in xml file?

Tags: java, xml, performance, xerces

I'm using the following code to parse an xml file using xerces 2.11:

```
@Test
public void testXercesPerformance() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException
{
    final SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    final SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
    final XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
    final InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("./some.xml")), 8192));
    xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
}
```

However the performance is very poor when the xml file just contains a few xml elements at the beginning and a large comment at the end (total file size about 10MB). In the course of parsing the parser successively allocates new Strings ending up at a total of 1.3TB of allocated strings (not all allocated at the same time). The parsing itself took 4 minutes to complete.

The file I used for testing started with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>helloworld-secure</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>assemble</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                            <programs>
                                <program>
                                    <mainClass>HelloWorld</mainClass>
                                    <name>webapp</name>
                                </program>
                            </programs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
<!-- 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>helloworld-secure</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
```

It then repeats the dependencies from the uncommented part hundreds of times until it reaches a size of nearly 10MB and ends with:

```
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>assemble</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                            <programs>
                                <program>
                                    <mainClass>HelloWorld</mainClass>
                                    <name>webapp</name>
                                </program>
                            </programs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
-->
```

What's the cause of this poor performance and how should I configure the parser to improve performance?

Comment: On my machine, without adding a schema source in the code, the XML I generated ~12MB is parsed in 300ms using the default content handler. Perhaps your handler is inefficient ? Can you post the handler's code ?

Comment: @DeepakBala I minimized the example once more and there is no content handler in use. The large majority of time is spend in `org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanComment`.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker are you restricted to using the `XMLReader` class? What data format are you looking for once the xml is parsed, are you just looking for xsd validation?

Comment: @ug_ I'm not restricted to `XMLReader`. In fact I could get rid of xerces completly. But anyway, this seems like a problem that should be solvable somehow configuring xerces correctly or might impose a bug in xerces.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker posted an awnser but in trying to reproduce the problem I came across some mixed results. Using your exact code I did see the very long parsing time however using the code in my awnser with the `XMLInputFactory` class I didnt see any significant time difference between using a `StreamFilter` to remove the comments. This would lead me to belive there is another way to speed up parsing. If my answer doesnt solve it for you I will happily delete it so you can pull more attention to your question by having it with 0 answers.

Comment: @ug_ I think you can leave your answer as it is, because I did not restrict answers to be using SAX only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been previously (well, more than 10 years ago) reported as [XERCESJ-970](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-970). It has been fixed in [revision 1507079 of xerces-j trunk](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/trunk/?p=1507079) since mid 2013.

The problem is a linearly growing buffer within `XMLStringBuffer` that too often needs to be reallocated.

The fix in my case was to rebuild xerces 2.11 with the patch from r1507079 applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StreamFilter` or `EventFilter` provided from the `XmlInputFactory` class, these 2 classes allow you to intercept the parsing behavior prior to the actual readers parsing. The `StreamCommentFilter` is class that will stop any comments from being parsed. I used your example and make a 20mb file and it parses it fast with the filter enabled or disabled on my computer. My computer happens to be quite fast but however on slower computer it may differ.

Imports for convenience:

```
import javax.xml.stream.StreamFilter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
```

---

```
// Create our factory and make sure its namespace aware.
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
// create the filtered reader that will not allow any comments to be parsed
XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createFilteredReader(
        xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(new File("./some.xml"))), 
        new StreamCommentRemovalFilter());

// transform our XmlStreamReader into a Document using a Transformer
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();

DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
transformer.transform(new StAXSource(reader), result);
Document document = (Document) result.getNode();
// do something with your document
```

The `StreamFilter` implementation, this will not allow any comments to actually be put into Java objects during parsing.

```
public static class StreamCommentRemovalFilter implements StreamFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        // if its a comment dont parse it
        if(reader.getEventType() == XMLEvent.COMMENT) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your example you also are including the namespace and Schema so I would assume you want to do some validation, if so you can still perform it using the `DOMSource` class with the parsed `Document` from the code above.

```
final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
final Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(new URL("http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd").openStream());
final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);

schema.newValidator().validate(new DOMSource(document.getFirstChild()));
```